# CSS Cascading rules W3C explanation pls

Tags: css, cascading

So we have w3c standards telling what precedence the CSS take when applying:

Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:

1. user agent declarations (from the user agent? (standard styling))
2. user normal declarations <- what is this?
3. author normal declarations <- what is this? (style sheets applied by me?)
4. important declarations (by me with !important flag)
5. user important declarations <- what is this?

It however does not explain what it means. Just dumps a declaration. What are user normal declarations? And so on what does this mean?

I know that when u apply CSS order is like this:

1. First styles from user agent
2. Than styles from external document
3. Styles from within  tag
4. inline styles

My question is: what do the 5 rules mean seperately?

Comment: I think it's more important the specificity, because if a rule have more specifity than other, even if second is an "author normal declaration", the first will be applied.

Comment: This question is either **too broad**, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: "I know that when u apply CSS order is like this ..." No it isn't. The order is that of the DOM, later rules take precedence over earlier one that have the same specificity. "author" means you. "user" means the user. "normal" means without !important. "important" means with !important.

Comment: 1: Browser Default Styles 2: External Style Sherts 3: Internal Style in <Head>. 4: Inline Styles.    Higher number takes precedent

Comment: User means the user? What user? User agent?

Comment: @GreatJobBob - No that's a myth. Try it. Put an external style sheet link after a <style> block. You'll see that the external style sheet rules override the <style> block ones.

Comment: @TerryvandenBerg - You know what a user is. It's the human who can't find the "any" key on their keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the following spec I assume: [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade)

As you see there is a description for the different origins and the cascading order at "6.4 The cascade".

In short that means:

1. user agent declarations: standard styling from the used user agent (browser)
2. user normal declarations: custom styles declared by the user
3. author normal declarations: styling declared by the author of the website
4. author important declarations: 3. with "!important" rule
5. user important declarations: 2. with "!important" rule

The term "user" stands for the person who is visiting the website.

Unfortunately the usage of user defined CSS is not really popular, so this order is also not really popular...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would a user create css for a page lol? using console?

Comment: AFAIK every common web browser used to implement the possibility for custom (user defined) stylesheets. Mostly by editing a special css file or including your own. By now (because it hasn't been used anyway) it's i.e. removed from Chrome, in Firefox there's a file you can add your stylesheets to, but it's quite good hidden (see https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/how-to-override-css-stylesheets-in-firefox/).

Comment: The people who can really benefit from a user stylesheet are those with particular sight difficulties. There are people who only read text if it's blue on white, for others it might be yellow on black. A user stylesheet allows them to override the author's scheme to help with their particular difficulty.

Comment: @Alohci Note that for the particular example you mention, it's enough to set "Override the colors specified by the page with my selections above" in Firefox's Options dialog. No need to fuss around with a user stylesheet!